# Installing PHP on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, windows

I have been trying to install PHP on a computer running Windows Server 2008 R2. I have had some success, because I can write scripts and run them from the folder `c:\php`.

The trouble is, I cannot run scripts from any other folders, and I need to do this.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information for us to help.  What web server are you using? What do you mean by "run scripts"? Are you talking about from the command line?  What steps have you taken to try and solve your issue?

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2008 R2. It is running IIS 7.0 software. By "run scripts", I mean running scripts from the command line. (Also, I want people to be able to access the scripts remotely, by making an HTTP request.) I have followed the exact instructions from the PHP website, but it does not seem to have worked.

Comment: There are limitations when running php on a Windows server. I've been running php on Windows servers for years, your best bet is to use something like xampp: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 2):

Use XAMPP (Apache-MySQL-PHP-Perl) for Windows.  Ive been using this for a few years and have been running Moodle on top of it.  Has good documentation and wide community support.

Tutorials for setup: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVcTqkHtNMg

documentation install guide/detail: http://www.a3webtech.com/index.php/xampp.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run PHP scripts (from the command line) from a directory other than `C:/PHP` you need to add the path containing `php.exe` (which is probably `C:/PHP`) to your `PATH` environment variable. You can then use `php yourscript.php` on the command line anywhere you like - just be wary that relative paths for `require()`'s and such won't work unless you're in the right place.

To have your scripts be served by your web server from different directories, you will need to configure your web server by creating a virtual directory. You'll need to refer to the documentation of your web server here, since you don't mention what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `c:\php.exe` to your Windows Path variable.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Answer (score 0):

Use the Web Platform Installer from Microsoft.  In the list it provides you will fine the latest version of PHP.  The installer will perform the installation for you properly.